Парсинг просмотров конкретного сообщения с помощью телеграмм бота
У меня есть бот, который забирает chat_id и message_id, после чего сохраняет его в базу данных. Два вопроса:

Как я могу с помощью бота узнавать просмотры данного сообщения?
Как через какое-то время сравнивать эти просмотры? То есть обращаться к этому сообщению и считывать с него информацию. (Насколько мне известно, раньше была функция get_chat_message, но ее убрали в aiogram3)

